# Access classifier artifacts of dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have some Maven projects that depend on one another. I was interested in having these artifacts produce some supporting artifacts that would be identified with the `classifier` tag. I could then like to consume these supporting artifacts downstream in a custom Maven plugin. For a given Maven project, how can I access the artifacts with a specific classifier tag?

Comment: Unclear. Do you want to have a dependency on an artifact that has a classifier?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a dependency on an artifact that has a classifier. But I also want to have a dependency on the same artifact id without the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency to an artifact having a classifier by adding the `<classifier>` element inside the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <classifier>myclassifier</classifier>
</dependency>
```

You could then have the same dependency element but without the classifier.